# IMCE image upload and permissions issue

Tags: 6, media, wysiwyg, files

I've implemented the IMCE module and added it to the CKEditor. When we upload files though, the resized images come out fine, but the uploaded file itself is saved in the same directory with incorrect file permissions, which causes the file to not be viewable in the browser.

Upon inspection, the uploaded file has no effective permissions for the IUSR account, but the resized images have the needed permissions for IUSR.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue?

We are running IIS7 with Drupal 6.

Answer (score 2):

The real issue is file permissions. When PHP uploads a file, it saves it in the temp directory. When that file then gets moved it retains the file permissions from the temp directory and does not inherit the destination folder permissions.

So check folder permissions of both your temp folder and the destination folder.