# Incorrect File Permissions When Images Are Uploaded in the CKEditor WYSIWYG using ElFinder on Windows

Tags: files, wysiwyg

When I upload and image in the WYSIWYG, the image is added to the /sites/default/files/ folder, but cannot be seen on the web becasue IIS_IUSRS does not have the correct file permissions. Also, the permissions are only viewable by an administrator.

I tried the answer given on [IMCE image upload and permissions issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8872/imce-image-upload-and-permissions-issue), but both the temp and destination folders give IIS_IUSRS and IUSRS read/write/modify. I have even tried temporarily giveing 'Everyone' full control to get this working, but that does not help.

[image: I have to click Advanced to view file permissions (I am logged in as an administrator)]

First, I have to click advanced to view the uploaded files permissions. I don't have to do that on the folders or other files in the folder.

Then I have to give Administrator permission. Again, this is not required on the folders or other files in the folder.
[image: Give Admin Permission]

Then I can see the file permissions and IIS_IUSRS has List folder/read data, not modify. Also, this is inherited from 'Parent Object' not the parent folder.
[image: Permissions]

If I click Disable inheritence and remove all permissions, then click enable inheritrance and apply, the correct permissions re inherited and the image can be seen on the web.
[image: Permissions after disabling then enabling inheritence]

Has anyone else experienced this? Why doesn't the uploaded file inherit the folder permissiosn correctly in the first place? Why do I have to disable then enable inheritence to get it to work?

I need to fix this because the web editors will be adding a lot of images and it is not practical for me to manually change the permissiosn every time.

I don't know if this is an error with Windows Server 2012, IIS 8.5, CKEditor or ElFinder.

I am using ElFinder, but was only able to tag this with CKfinder. I am using Plupload as well, but can't remember if it integrates with ElFidner or not.

P.S. This site is stil in development. I will remove 'Everyone' before it goes live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to correct this by enabling inheritance on the c:\windows\temp folder, after verifying that the IIS_IUSRS (machinename) account has read & execute/list folder contents/read permissions.  I was prompted about a potential security risk, but ultimately this fixed it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay responding - I was away. That worked. Thanks!